# Excel Macro to compare two columns in two different sheets and replace their value with a sequential number

Tags: vba, excel

How to create a macro that takes students ID in two columns in two different worksheets and changes their values to a new sequential number?

Answer (score 0):

I created the code and it works correctly

```
Sub Macro13()
Dim i As Long
Dim myValue1 As Double, myValue2 As Double, seqNo As Double
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row
seqNo = 1

For i = 2 To LastRow

     myValue1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i).Value
     myValue2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
      If myValue1 = myValue2 Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & i).Value = seqNo
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = seqNo
        seqNo = seqNo + 1
      End If
     Next i
 End Sub
```